# Elementary transparent theme not working properly

Tags: release-freya, settings, themes, window-management

I installed the elementary-transparent-theme and used the tweak tools to change the GTK+ and metacity themes to transparent. The transparent theme works fine in GTK+ windows, but in metacity windows (such as google chrome, libre office, etc) it doesn`t work (white bar instead of transparent bar). Anyone has an idea of how can I solve this? Thanks.

[image: White bar appears instead of transparent bar]

Answer (score 2):

Metacity does not support the alpha (transparency) channel.